# How to set ng-style for Radio, checkbox and File in Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, types

Below code is working for buttons, without using ngstyle.

```html
<input  type="{{y.cellNumber}}"  src="{{y.src}}"  value="{{y.name}}" style="height:20px;width:50px">
```

But if i use ngstyle unable to display the buttons, how to do it using ngstyle

```html
<input  type="{{y.cellNumber}}"  
        src="{{y.src}}"  value="{{y.name}}" 
        [style.height.px]="y.height*2"  
        [style.width.px]="y.width/2"   
        [style.background]="y.background" 
        [style.color]="y.color" >
```

Answer (score 0):

To use NgStyle for this example:

```
<input 
[ngStyle]="{ 'background': y.background, 'color': y.color, 'height.px': y.height*2 , 'width.px': y.width/2 }">
```

Comment: I created an example, you 'll find in stackblitz.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngstyle-example?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: ya its working in your example but in my code image,video,text displayed, but same code didn't display radio, checkbox and file.I don't the reason. It didn't show me any error.